# Is there a way to find out if Python threading locks are ever used by more than one thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm working on a personal project that has been refactored a number of times. It started off using multithreading, then parts of it used asyncio, and now it is back to being mainly single threaded.

As a result of all these changes I have a number of threading.Lock()'s in the code that I would like to remove and cleanup to prevent future issues.

How can I easily work out which locks are in use and hit by more than one thread during the runtime of the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am in the situation to find that out, I would try to replace the lock with a wrapper that do the counting (or print something, raise an exception, etc.) for me when the undesired behavior happened. Python is hacky, so I can simply create a function and overwrite the original `threading.Lock` to get the job done. That might need some careful implementation, e.g., catch both all possible pathway to lock and unlock.

However, you have to be careful that even so, you might not exercise all possible code path and thus never know if you really remove all "bugs".

Comment: I thought about subclassing threading.Lock with a counter per thread , but was hoping  that there would be some tool pre-made out there to help. If it's the case that manually implementing it is the only way then so be it.